# Correct position for submenu in html 5

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

i cant get my submenu to hover directly below the correct menu, instead all submenu are hovering at the same position. Any help how to get my submenu to hover correctly would be a big help.

here is the css code:

```
menu {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-45px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    border-top:1px solid #999;
}

menu ul {
    margin:0;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
menu ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:15px;
    display:inline;
}

menu ul li a, menu ul li ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#003;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    font-size:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:4px;

}

menu ul li ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}

menu ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    background-color:#CCC;
    height:auto;
    width:120px;
    padding:0;
}

menu ul li ul li{
    clear:both;
}
```

here is the html code:

```
<menu>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">MENU 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>    
        <li><a href="#">MENU 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">MENU 4</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
menu ul li {
   position: relative;
}

menu ul li:hover > ul {
   display: block;
}

menu ul li > ul {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;

   display: none;
}
```

This positions the right submenu under the list-items.

Comment: thanks, ths works, i only needed to do the position to relative which i forgot to do